# Div Layout Issue with Positioning

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<body>
    <div class="main">

        <div class="topBar">
            <p>testing</p>
        </div>

        <div class="content">

            <div class="broadcastBar">
                <p>testing</p>
            </div>

            <div class="mainBody">
                <p>more testing</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>    
</body>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
div.main {

}

div.topBar {
    background-color: Black;
    color: White;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

div.broadcastBar {
    background-color: Gray;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

div.content {
    background-color: Yellow;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

My question is this.  As you can see by the markup and CSS, I'm trying to have `div`s be the sections of the screen.  But because `<div class="content" />` has a `position` of `absolute`, it is causing the div to push below the browser window by `50px` (which is what it is relative to the `topBar`).

I've tried making it so that the `content` `div` doesn't have to be position `absolute`, but everything just pushes the `div`s all around and the `div` edges are no longer flush to each other or the browser window.

Any idea what I can do hear to alleviate my issue?

#### Edit

*Added desired output*:  this screenshot is currently what the above markup and CSS render.  This is what I'm going for (for the most part, without the extended/scroll bar effect).  I want to have my `divs` flush against each other and to the browser window.

What is the best way to do this if not through `absolute` positioning?

[image]

Comment: explain at first what your goal is. Only from your code I can't see any reason for an absolute positioning at all.

Comment: What exactly is the problem, what you want to happen?

Comment: Check out css-tricks.com for some great CSS tutorials.

Comment: @SvenBieder please see my edit to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are going to want to learn is using some standard formatting practises with **float**.

Using absolute to position your elements will in the long run hurt you. If all your elements are using float, you will be able to better control their appearance.

### For Example:

```
div.topBar {
    background-color: Black;
    color: White;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

div.broadcastBar {
    background-color: Gray;
    width: 70%;
    height: 80%;
    float: left;
}

div.content {
    background-color: Yellow;
    width: 30%;
    height: 80%;
    float: left;
}
```

### @EDIT:

So you Have 3 divs and you will want to stack them sequencially.

```
<div class="header">headerdiv</div>
<div class="left">leftdiv</div>
<div class="right">rightdiv</div>
```

Float follows this sequence so that by using these properties, elelments will be forced to fall after one another based on space constraints:

```
div.header {
    background-color: Black;
    color: White;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

div.left {
    background-color: Gray;
    height: 80%;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

div.right {
    background-color: Yellow;
    height: 80%;        
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
```

### @QUESTION:

So If you need to use pixel measurements, then you will need to encapsulate all of the elements in another container with the *max width and height* that your layout will be.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">headerdiv</div>
    <div class="left">leftdiv</div>
    <div class="right">rightdiv</div>
</div>

div.container{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

div.header {
    background-color: Black;
    color: White;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

div.left {
    background-color: Gray;
    height: 80px;
    width: 70px;
    float: left;
}

div.right {
    background-color: Yellow;
    height: 80px;        
    width: 30px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Please see my edit to my question.  So you're still recommending using `float` to give me the same layout with more "sense"?

Comment: Yes I'll give you CSS to do what You are trying to achieve in a second.

Comment: Alright see edit. Alternatively, you cna use float:right on the element on the right. Both will work.

Comment: Ok, that definitely looks much better.  But how can I do this with exact widths and heights?  Instead of `%`, how can I do this with `px`?  For instance, I want `div.right` to be `width: 300px`.  And also `div.header` I would want to make fixed.  Say `50px`.  But then that messed up `div.left` and `div.right` because they have a `height` of `%`.  See what I mean?

Comment: encapsulate the divs with the max width and height you want your layout to be